# How to compare strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to compare two strings in JavaScript, but my code isn't working.

I think `if(answer==correct_answer_arr[0])` is wrong, but I don't know
what the problem is, or how I can fix it.

*I already checked that "correct_answer_arr" has no problem, which has correct information

**JS Code:**

```
var correct_answer_arr = new Array();

$('document').ready(function() {
  var str;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('get', 'http://localhost:8080/new/text.jsp', true);
  request.onload = function() {
    str = request.responseText;
    correct_answer_arr = str.split(",");
  };
  request.send();
});

function keycheck(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var answer = $("input").val();
    if (answer == correct_answer_arr[0]) {
      alert("correct");
    } else {
      alert("wrong");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `==` will compare strings, what makes you think it is wrong? console.log both values to see if they are what you think they are

Comment: where are you calling keycheck?

Comment: also `$('document')` won't select the document, it is `$(document)`

Comment: Do you only have one `<input>` on your page? The comparison will be 'wrong' if you don't have a valid answer in `$("input").val()`.

Comment: Are you calling `keycheck` before the request has returned?

Comment: And did you check `responseText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do `console.log(correct_answer_arr);` before and after the `str.split(",")` to see what's going on.

Please also check if *answer* get's set to `undefined` because it's a common error when calling `$().val()` on an empty collection.
As already mentioned, **document** is a reserved keyword and should not be written in quotemarks in this case.

Also it's good practice to use **===** instead of **==**.

Comment: i checked everything you said but my codes still doesn't work i think something happens when i get data with ajax.. string which is got with ajax has invisible control character?